# C++ - How do I create a vector where every element is a single digit from an input string?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write a function that takes a user input of digits, e.g. 830948234681764 and creates a vector with as many values as the full length of that input, and creates one element for every digit:

Input: 830948234681764

- index - value

  - 0 - 8
  - 1 - 3
  - 2 - 0
  - 3 - 9
  - 4 - 4
  - 5 - 8

etc

I've had issues using maths to extract the individual digits because the sequence has to be potentially several thousand characters long.

Using a string, however, means that each element of the vector becomes that digits's ascii code, and I'm not sure how to convert them to the original values.

Here's the meat of the code:

```
    string s = "12345"
    int size = s.length();
    std::vector <double> v (size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        v[i] = s[i];
}
```

Whether it's converting the array from ascii to int values afterwards, or taking each character and converting it to an int before injecting it into the vector, I'm new to C++ and am a bit stuck figuring this one out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Hint: `'0' - '0' == 0;  '1' - '0' == 1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: How are you getting the input (I assume it's into a std::string?), or do you already have it in an int/long/etc?

Comment: @Water It's into a std::string at the moment, yes

Comment: Use `std::transform` instead of writing a loop.  The name of that function describes what you are doing.  *Here's the meat of the code:* -- Post a [mcve], as we 1) don't know what `InputSequence` is, and 2) Your `CreateVector` function creates a local vector and returns, thus destroying the vector you just created.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the hint! So C++ converts characters into ints(?) when used in a calculation, with - '0' seeming to be a common way to do so without any offset. Any reason why - '0' would be preferred over + '0' at all?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Cheers for the tip! I went ahead and cleaned up my code.

Comment: Essentially, `'0'` is just another way to write `48` (which happens to be an ASCII code of character `'0'`); `'1'` is a way to write `49` and so on. Naturally, `'0' - '0' == 48 - 48 == 0` - the integral value of character `'0'` in decimal notation. `'0' + '0' == 48+48 == 96` doesn't have any particular meaning; not sure why you are mentioning it.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the logic involved, glad I asked. Judging by the code I read below and what I've implemented, it appeared that by merely including a string digit in a calculation, C++ converts it from ascii to a pure value. The reality is far simpler, I'm simply subtracting 48 from every value... I do appreciate the help, I'm very new!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is the push the successive digits into an initially empty vector.

```
 std::string s = "07563157289";

 std::vector<int> v;
 for (auto c : s) {                // for each char in s
    v.push_back(c - '0');
 }
```

An alternative is to first create the vector with the right size, then use a loop over indices to fill the vector

```
 unsigned size = s.size();
 std::vector<int> v(size);
 for (unsigned i=0; i<size; ++i) {     // for i in {0,1, ..size-1}
    v[i] = s[i] - '0';
 }
```

It is slightly more efficient with huge strings, because it avoids the costs of (hidden) reallocations of the underlying array.

**EDIT**: I compiled several versions (with g++ --std=c++11 -Os -S) to have a look on the code produced by the compiler.

The winner is

```
std::vector<int> digits_transform_alloc(const std::string &s)
{
   std::vector<int> v(s.size());
   std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), 
                  v.begin(),
                  [](char ch) { return ch - '0';});
   return v;
}
```

where the vector is first allocated to the right size, then filled with values.  The loop is 5 machine instructions only.

```
.L61:
    cmpq    %r13, %rax
    je  .L66
    movl    $0, (%r12,%rax,4)
    incq    %rax
    jmp .L61
```

And the same code is generated for the "declare vector with size + for loop with index" version (1st ex-aequo).

Using transform+back_inserter is 2x-longer and involves a costly call to an auxiliary procedure (about 50 instructions) for emplace_back

```
.L48:
    cmpq    %r12, %rbp
    je  .L54
    movsbl  0(%rbp), %edx
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rsi
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    subl    $48, %edx
    movl    %edx, 12(%rsp)
.LEHB2:
    call    _ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE12emplace_backIIiEEEvDpOT_
.LEHE2:
    incq    %rbp
    jmp .L48
```

Comment: `.reserve()` and then `.push_back()`s are also an option.  I usually prefer that to `resize()`s and then assignments.  In the general case, that is usually more efficient, since it minimizes the calls to constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: Thanks very much! The second option works perfectly, and probably makes the most sense for this project considering I'll always know the size of the vector I'm filling.

Comment: @Curious In the case of a vector of int's, there are no extra cost involved in constructors and assignment operators.
Playing with reserve and push_back will cost an extra test at each push_back to check the size against the capacity.

Comment: @MichelBillaud that's why i mentioned it in a comment and explained why i said it was an option :) augmenting the first example with a reserve will likely speed things up

Comment: reserve will prevent reallocations, but not tests on the size, which can be avoided.  Better use a transform to a previously sized vector (in the case of `int`` where no constructor call is involved) + an ordinary iterator instead of a back_inserter. See machine codes above.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the loops and use `std::transform`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
//...
std::string InputSequence;
std::vector <double> MainVector;
//...
std::transform(InputSequence.begin(), InputSequence.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(MainVector), [](char ch) { return ch - '0'; });
```

Comment: Yes, but is it worth it ? Why do you use `double` ?

Comment: I used `double` since that is what the OP used in this case.  I could have easily templatized this to take any type that can convert from `char`. But as far as being worth it -- many proponents of STL make it a point to not have to write loops, and instead use the algorithm functions.  The reason is that 1) it is very difficult to introduce bugs or non-optimal code when using the algorithm functions -- basically the functions just "work", 2) When you see the algorithm function, you know exactly what is being done (no need to figure out what is being done in the loop).

Comment: Well, in the text the OP wrote "converting the array from ascii to int values" which was a more reasonablespecification  than the code sample he gave (with wrong stop condition in the for loop...) under the admission he was new to programming.
Anyway, I understand the standard algorithm functions are a great value, but I wouldn't not say they're the better tool for all jobs.
When you see the simple for loop, you don't need to figure out why you need a back inserter :-)

Comment: @MichelBillaud I have to admit that the original code I entered used a double, and then I later translated my source code to something more readable (which is where I managed to incorrectly write the loop, d'oh!).